# Embedding video

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way of embedding YouTube or Vimeo videos into a form?

I'm looking to show a video and then use a form to collect responses.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

At the moment we do not offer a way to add a video to a Cognito Form. You can embed your Cognito Form on your own website, and then embed a video next to the form.

This is a feature on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/h8AsILu1), you can follow our progress on this feature and other features that you would like to see us work on.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately we don't have the option to embed the video next to the form. The option to put an iframe etc in a form would be brilliant.